# should I say "fight" or "fight against"

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct?

*Immune system fights tumor and infection.
Immune system fights against tumor and infection.*

Thanks!

Comment: Both are correct: the former is a transitive usage of the verb _fight_, and the latter an intransitive usage. There isn't a significant difference between the two in this case.

Comment: ...except you should probably have a definite article there.

Comment: Yes, _the immune system._

Comment: I agree with @user405662. Both are correct and "the" needs to appear before "immune system." I'd also like to add that "tumor" isn't a noncount noun like "infection" is, so you need to either write "tumors" if you are speaking generally or write "the tumor" if not speaking generally but speaking specifically about a certain case or incidence.

Comment: I perceive a slight difference in sense. *fights infection* suggests that it fights after the person is infected. *fights against* suggests that it fends off the infection before the person gets infected.

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat: What about _She fought her cancer bravely._ and _She fought against her cancer bravely._ Is the first one wrong then?

Comment: @user405662: Neither is wrong, and they can both convey the same meaning. But I would choose *she bravely fought her cancer* over *she bravely fought against her cancer* -- it seems more idiomatic, in AmE, anyway.

Comment: @user405662: It *could* mean that. Eating kale every day fights against [fights off] cancer.